# Can someone with albinism have red hair with very pale skin and blue eyes?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, human-genetics, mutations

I have heard of a type of albinism that occurs in races with darker skin that can give people red hair, but in the pictures I've seen, they usually have reddish-brown hair, a medium skin tone, and brown eyes.

Would it be possible for someone to have the very pale skin and light blue eyes typically associated with albinism while also having red hair? I have seen a picture of someone with this appearance, but their hair looked like it could have been dyed since it was brighter than natural red hair usually is.

If there is no form of albinism that causes this, is it a form that could possibly exist, or is there a particular reason that those traits couldn't come together?

Comment: Just a terminology note: race is a social construct, not a biological distinction. The American Association of Physical Anthropologists' 2019 statement on [Race and Racism](https://physanth.org/about/position-statements/aapa-statement-race-and-racism-2019/) may help you understand the issue more.